# How do I get the list of groups for a user through the Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I see how to get the list of groups, and how to get the members of each, but is there no way to get the list of groups a user (not just me) is a member of?  I'm using v4 of the API on 11.9.11-ee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. The API currently does not provide this capability. If it was added it would likely be an admin-only endpoint.

If you'd like to see this, raise a feature request at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues.